# element showing in design window but not showing in the emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, emulation

I'm designing a screen where the user will be able to click on the plus sign that you will see in the design window, but whenever I run the code it doesn't show on the emulator.
did anyone face this kind of problem, I wanted to upload some of the code but it's too long.
[image]

**XML file**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_toolbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"


        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_dashboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="338dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="338dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="659dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "I wanted to upload some of the code but it's too long." – You'll need to put together a [mcve], then. There's really not enough information here for us to be able to determine your specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Your XML code should look like this in a coordinatorlayout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_fab_chart" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Your MainActivity.Kt file, if you are using Kotlin should look like this

```
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
}


}
```

> If you are using java your MainActivity.java file should look like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you check the XML code I have just uploaded on the question, I tried what you added but still it's not showing

Comment: I think you should try and update your android studio alongside your emulator